# MYSQL - Select all rows in a table where it's ids in another table as string field

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table "**location**" and a table "**films**"

**location structure**

> id  |  name  |  position

**film structure**

> id  |  name  |  locations

where **film.locations** is a varchar field contains comma separated values of **location.id**

**EG**
location DATA

```
id  |  NAME    |  POSITION
 1  |  name1   |  p1
 2  |  name2   |  p2
```

film data

```
id  |  name   |  locations
 1  |  name1  |  1,3
 2  |  name2  |  2,5
 3  |  name3  |  1,2,13,23,45,66,4,222,54321,(and so on)
```

I want all the rows from table location where **location.id**(s) are inside **film.locations** field

Thank you guys!

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: How to get all the rows from table location where location.id(s) are inside film.locations field ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`find_in_set`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function on the join:

```
SELECT *
FROM   locations l
JOIN   film f ON FIND_IN_SET(l.id, f.locations) > 0
```

Comment: Ok, it works, but the query take too much time. I suggest to select only some fields from table locations and add the GROUP BY locations.id option that avoid duplicates ids